# Caesar Cipher with a twist (Mysterious Error)

Tags: c++, encryption, file-io

I am assigned to write a cipher that takes in a file with characters on it, and change all the characters by a number (1-10). The hard part is what is needed in the encryption. "The key value with be incremented by one every time a new line is processed. However, the key is reset every five (rotation value) lines and returned to its original value"

e.g.: if a user enters 3 for a key, then lines 1,2,3,4, and 5 are encrypted with 3,4,5,6, and 7 respectively. Line 6 is then encrypted with 3, and so on.

At the moment, I can not even get a simple shift to work properly. Without any syntax errors, it compiles with no error. However, when I go to open the output file, my text editor crashes because I somehow have created a 510mb text file..... I know :/

So I am looking for any assistance you are willing to give. Been working on this for more than a few hours now and figured it was about time to ask for some help. Thank you all in advance for any advice/solutions you are willing to take the time to give. :)

```
/*
*File: Lab5
*Author: Nathaniel Goodhue
*Created on: 10/14/15
*Description: Encrypts an input message by
*shifting characters by a given number        
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/*
*Displays a menu that allows the user to set a shift key value,
*encrypt or decrypt a message, or quit
*/
void displayMenu()
{
   cout<<"1. Set the shift key value"<<endl;
   cout<<"2. Encrypt"<<endl;
   cout<<"3. Decrypt"<<endl;
   cout<<"4. Quit"<<endl;
}

/*
*gets the value that characters will be shifted by
*/
int getKeyValue(int &keyValue)
{
   keyValue = 0;
   do
   {
      cout<<"Enter the shift key value between 1 and 10: ";
      cin >>keyValue;
      if(keyValue >10 ||keyValue <1)
         cout<<"Key value must be between 1 and 10."<<endl;
   }
   while(keyValue >10 || keyValue <1);
   return keyValue;
}

/*
*gets the input and output file names
*/
void getFileNames(ifstream &fin1, ofstream &fout1, ifstream  &fin2, ofstream &fout2)
{
   fin1.open("inputMsg.txt");
   fout1.open("encryptedMsg.txt");
   fin2.open("encriptedMsg.txt");
   fout2.open("revertedMsg.txt");
}

/*
*shifts characters in input file by (int keyValue)
*/
void encrypt(int &keyValue, ifstream &fin1, ofstream &fout1)
{
   char ch;
   while(!fin1.eof())
   { 
      fin1.get(ch);
      while(ch != ' ')
      {
         fout1<<static_cast <char> (static_cast <int>(ch)+keyValue);
      }
   }
}

/*
*shifts characters back to original 
*/
void decrypt(int &keyValue, ifstream &fin2, ofstream &fout2)
{

   char ch;
   while(!fin2.eof())
   {
      fin2.get(ch);
      while(ch != ' ')
      {
         fout2<<static_cast <char> (static_cast <int>(ch)-keyValue);
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   int menuChoice, keyValue;
   ifstream fin1;
   ofstream fout1;
   ifstream fin2;
   ofstream fout2;

   getFileNames(fin1, fout1, fin2, fout2);
   do{   
      displayMenu();
      cin >> menuChoice;
      if (menuChoice == 1)
      {
         getKeyValue(keyValue);
      }  
      else if (menuChoice == 2)
      {
     cout<<"Message successfully encrypted with "<<keyValue<<" as its key value"<<endl;
         encrypt(keyValue, fin1, fout1);
      }
      else if (menuChoice == 3)
      {
         cout<<"Message successfully decrypted with "<<keyValue<<" as its key value"<<endl;
         decrypt(keyValue, fin2, fout2);
      }
      else if(menuChoice > 4 || menuChoice < 1)
         cout<<"Invalid menu choice. Must be between 1 and 4";
   }
   while(menuChoice != 4);
   fin1.close();
   fout1.close();
   fin2.close();
   fout2.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Also the reason I have 4 files is because of the need for the decypher function.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the encrypt function. Specifically this bit:

```
  fin1.get(ch);
  while(ch != ' ')
  {
     fout1<<static_cast <char> (static_cast <int>(ch)+keyValue);
  }
```

On the first run through the loop, `fin1.get(ch)` sets `ch` to the first character of the input file. Then you enter a `while` loop which puts the (cyphered) first character into the file, over and over until `ch` is a space. But you read the next character *outside* this loop, so the condition to end the loop is never reached.

A simple `if` statement is all you need to avoid cyphering the spaces. In addition to that, your current code would always pick up (and cypher) the EOF, as the EOF bit doesn't get set until you try to read the end of the file (which is done in the loop, so doesn't get checked until after you cypher and append to file). You can use the ifstream's `good()` to check if there's any issue (either EOF or an error) within the loop and `break` if so, to avoid the EOF causing an extra character at the end:

```
void encrypt(int &keyValue, ifstream &fin1, ofstream &fout1)
{
   char ch;
   while(fin1.get(ch))
   {
      if(!fin1.good()) break;
      if (ch != ' ') fout1<<static_cast <char> (static_cast <int>(ch)+keyValue);
      else fout1<<' ';
   }
}
```

You'll need to make similar changes to your decryption, too. Also, to be picky, I'd suggest that

```
cout<<"Message successfully encrypted with "<<keyValue<<" as its key value"<<endl;
```

and the corresponding decryption line should come *after* successfully encrypting/decrypting, not before.

An extra problem is the way the file streams are all opened at the start of the program and closed at the end. This will fail if you try to encrypt and decrypt a message in the same run of the program, because `fin2` opens `encryptedMsg.txt` before the message is actually written to it. `fout1` (which writes the encrypted message to that file) needs to be closed first.

I'd actually suggest just in general that you only open the streams when you need them. Rather than opening all streams at the beginning and closing all streams at the end, just open `fin1` (the input message) and `fout1` (the encrypted output) before encrypting the message, and close them immediately afterwards. Similarly, open `fin2` (the encrypted message as input) and `fout2` (the decrypted version) immediately before decrypting, and close them immediately afterwards. Or, even better, you can reuse the streams - just have one `ifstream` object and one `ofstream` object, which each open and close the appropriate files before and after encryption/decryption.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! that certainly solved the loop error, but now im getting a blank output file, even with that exact code. my input is just five lines of the alphabet in uppercase and lowercase

Comment: sorry, I misremembered something about how ifstreams work, I think I was getting confused with some external library I used once. Try with the edit I just made.

Comment: @NatGoodhue oh, wait, I just spotted something. Firstly: you'll have to rework how you open the file streams. Currently you open all of them at the start of the program and close them all at the end, which means you're reading the encrypted message before it's been written. You need to close `fout1` before reading the encrypted message, otherwise the input stream won't see the message. Also you have a typo in your `fin2` filename ('encripted' vs 'encrypted')

Answer (score 0):

Your program never stops reading the input files. If your input file does not contain a space character then this cycle will run forever, and this is what causes the very large output.

```
while(ch != ' ')
```

Change these two lines to

```
while(fin1.good())
```

to make it stop at file end (EOF).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for that, solved the issue of memory. If you have any advice for the encryption itself, that would be extremely appreciated. What i have now just gave me a blank output file for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do everything at once.  Start with a simple program to read a file and do a standard Caesar shift on it.  When, and only when, you have that working correctly proceed to the second stage with the stepping key every end-of-line.

Doing it that way you can deal with a few errors at a time, rather then having them all lumped together.  It is also easier to work out which part of your code is causing your error.